# Creating Multiple-Window Application with Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, multi-window

I am making a simulation application. It requires to have multiple windows (application windows not GUI windows) that each window have the ability to interact ... like one for Camera view port , another for GUI , etc.

Is there any chance to do that with unity ???

Comment: Something like [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/10206/how-can-i-show-split-screen-or-multiple-camera-vie.html) should get you started.

Comment: @Jerdak I meant Application Windows .. this link is about GUI windows.

Comment: It would help if you included a mockup of what you are trying to achieve.  The term "GUI windows" is ambiguous and could refer to multiple viewports or the Unity's `GUI.Window` widgets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should create multiple applications and use interprocess communications (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx). As far as I know there is no direct way to tell Unity to create the application in multiple application windows.

Comment: Yes that's the only possible answer .. I Did that through unity built in network . But i am afraid of performance issues .. opening 3 or 4 empty unity application Simultaneously rise cpu usage up to 90% . Whats happen when they contain other stuff ????

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can have as many [cameras](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-Camera.html) displaying [different things](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/44911-2-cameras-running-the-same-time) in [different parts of your window](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/10206/how-can-i-show-split-screen-or-multiple-camera-vie.html) as you would like.

You can even make [popup windows](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.Window.html).

Everything should be able to interact.

Comment: As i said ... I meant Application Windows .. Not GUI Windpws